# DUVIDA - Substituição de textos com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5, delphi

Bem, estou montando um sistema de chat em Delphi no qual utilizo o componente Chromium para carregar um HTML que utilizo como o histórico do chat devido a falta de componentes visuais no mesmo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Enfim, nos balões de mensagens é possível notar aquele velho "V" de confirmação que nada mais é que o seguinte código:

```
<i class="material-icons readStatus">done</i>
```

Ou seja, quando o remetente visualiza a mensagem, preciso alterar todos os "done" para "done_all". Pesquisei bastante e não achei nada relacionado a alterar vários textos já impressos no HTML, até achei uma função que acreditei que solucionaria o meu problema, mas por algum motivo a mesma não está funcionando.

```
function replaceText(selector, text, newText, flags) {
 var matcher = new RegExp(text, flags);
 var elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector), i;

 for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
  if (!elems[i].childNodes.length)
   elems[i].innerHTML = elems[i].innerHTML.replace(matcher, newText);
}

function readStatusIcon(oldStatus, newStatus) {
 replaceText('*', oldStatus, newStatus, 'g');
}

## Nessa função "readStatusIcon" eu passo ">done<" e ">done_all<" pelo ##
## Delphi para ele não se confundir com outra parte do código ##
```

---

```
<section class="mainApp">
 <div class="rightPanel">
  <div class="convHistory userBg">
   <!-- CONVERSATION GOES HERE! -->
   <msg></msg>
   <div class="msg messageSent">
    EAE
    <i class="material-icons readStatus">done</i>
     <span class="timestamp">10:20 AM</span>
   </div>
   <div class="msg messageSent">
    EAE
    <i class="material-icons readStatus">done</i>
     <span class="timestamp">10:20 AM</span>
   </div>
   <div class="msg messageSent">
    EAE
    <i class="material-icons readStatus">done</i>
     <span class="timestamp">10:20 AM</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

O código

**@EDIT:** Galera, deu certo, é como o nosso colega Felipe respondeu, removendo somente o `!` dessa linha `if (!elems[i].childNodes.length)`, o problema foi resolvido. Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Esse `if (!elems[i].childNodes.length)` está correto? Porque ele vai executar o replace, justamente, nos nós que não tem filhos, talvez `!` resolva o seu problema...

Comment: Não seria apenas uma substituição simples? -> `elems[i].textContent = "done_all";`.

Comment: o toggleClass não funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Cara não sei muito bem como está o seu código mas pq vc não faz assim:

```js
replaceText('mensagens', 'done_all');

function replaceText(selector, newText) {
 var elems = document.getElementById(selector).getElementsByTagName('i');

 for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
   elems[i].textContent = newText;
}
```

```html
<div id="mensagens">
  <i class="material-icons readStatus">Done</i>
  <i class="material-icons readStatus">Done</i>
  <i class="material-icons readStatus">Done</i>
  <i class="material-icons readStatus">Done</i>
  <i class="material-icons readStatus">Done</i>
</div>
```